# Aegis, customization points, and power points

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, aegis

When the Aegis levels up and gains more basic powers for the suit, he can form, change type and dismiss the suit if he likes or needs it. This takes a specific action depending on the new type of suit (swift, move, full-round), and does not require paying power points or customization points.

To confirm that I really understand: Now the Aegis can learn (or gain) non-basic powers for the suit and so he needs to change from basic power of i.e. Astral skin (nimble, speed and so on) for a non-basic power i.e. Darkvision that need 1 pp. Finally in the morning he can choose from basic to non-basic powers paying power points too, if he wants to change from basic to non-basic powers during the day he needs to use the reconfigure ability and then the customization points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not have to change free (“basic”) customizations in order to get the “non-basic” customizations: you get both. So for example, at 1st level, you have 3 customization points, and *diehard* costs 3 customization points, so you can choose it. Choosing it takes 8 hours. After choosing it, you have 0 customization points left, but your astral suit will have the *diehard* feature—in addition to the basic, free features available for a suit of that type. So in total your options are

- Astral suit with *nimble* (free), *speed* ×2 (free), and *diehard*.
- Astral armor with *brawn* (free), *improved damage* (free), and *diehard*.
- Astral juggernaut with *fortification* (free), *hardy* (free), and *diehard*.

Finally, the aegis class doesn’t use power points for customizing his suit; that relies solely on customization points. You can change how all of your customization points are spent by working on the suit for 8 hours, or you can change how some of your customization points are spent by using reconfigure.

The aegis’s power points aren’t used for very much: they are required to use the *crystallized weapon*, *empowered blast*, *harness power stone*, and *harness shard* customizations. So, in those four cases, you spend customization points to add those features to your suit, and then you spend power points using those features. Otherwise, the aegis has no use for power points.