# Spending customization points

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, aegis

From [an answer to a previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/161376/4563):

> So for example, at 1st level, you have 3 customization points, and *diehard* costs 3 customization points, so you can choose it. Choosing it takes 8 hours. After choosing it, you have 0 customization points left, but your astral suit will have the *diehard* feature

This means that the Aegis must choose his customization points before going to sleep (or meditation), right? However if the Aegis uses 1 or more customization points, he must sleep 8 hours (or meditate For Elan race) and not 8 hours each customization Point.

Anyway e.g. a 5th-level Aegis has 8 customization points, going to sleep he chooses Brawn (2 customization points),  (1 more the basic so Str +4) and Push (1 customization points), total 3 customization points on 8 and he keep last 5 customization points free; during the day he need to charge his astral suite with Harness Power Stone, Improved (that needs Power Stone Repository) so 3+2 customization points and he finish them. However, he needs 8 hours of sleep to obtain the effects, right? Except *Ultimate Psionics* says "on fly".

At this point he can use reconfigure to obtain the same effect immediately, or not?

If the Aegis uses reconfigure and now has "Harness Power Stone, Improved" but he lost 1 "brawn", he still has the basic, free brawn for Str +2, right?

At the end there are no ways to have more customization points over the table 2.2 Aegis (*Ultimate Psionics*) limit?

Comment: So this is really more than one Question, and some of it is probably better off as comments seeking clarification on my previous answer. If nothing else, the question about using *harness shard* should be its own Question.

Comment: In fact, I just corrected my previous answer, to mention *harness power stone* and *harness shard*, and I removed the question about using *harness shard from this question. You can find the old version of the question, that included that bit, [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/ae0f1b4c-7ce1-4794-80c8-887c7d846443/view-source), so you can easily create a new, dedicated question for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways for an aegis to spend customization points:

- In order to create his initial astral suit, as well as to recreate it from scratch (recovering all customization points and able to spend them all however he likes, regardless of how they were spent before), he can **work on it for 8 hours**. This is **not sleep**—he has to actually be awake and working on the suit for this—similar to crafting. Any sleep (or meditation) he needs, e.g. for power points, has to be done separately from this work. He does not need to perform this work every day, however: only when he wants to recreate the suit from scratch. Otherwise the suit will just stay the way it is.
- If the aegis has unspent customization points, either because he left some unspent during the 8 hours or because he leveled up and got more points, he can spend those points with just **1 minute of work**. This is what *Ultimate Psionics* meant by “on the fly.” **He cannot change any existing customization choices this way.**
- If the aegis is at least 3rd level, he can **reconfigure** the suit a certain number of times per day (once at 3rd, more as he levels up). When he does so, he “un-chooses” up to Int customization points worth of customizations, so his suit no longer has those, but he gets the points back and can spend them on new customizations. This process takes a **standard action**.

So you are mostly correct here, but with some important distinctions:

- Customization work is **not sleep**, so being an elan aegis makes no difference for that. That does affect refreshing the aegis’s power points.
- You get the benefits of your choices for unspent points **immediately after spending the 1 minute working on the suit to add them**. So your aegis has *improved harness power stone* after just 1 minute, and does not need to sleep at all.
- *Power stone repository* and *improved harness power stone* are 1-point and 2-point customizations, not 2-point and 3-point as you said. So after adding them, you would still have 2 customization points unspent.
- Reconfigure isn’t about spending unspent points, it’s about recycling points you actually did spend. So, for example, if you had taken *pull* and *ram* with your initial customizations (spending 6 points and leaving 2 unspent), and you wanted *improved harness power stone*, you could use reconfigure to remove *pull* and *ram* in order to take *power stone repository* and *improved harness power stone*.

  Still, the wording is unclear, and as a GM I would certainly let you use reconfigure just to spend unspent points, if you felt that you couldn’t afford to spend a whole minute doing that normally.

Otherwise, you are correct. You have the right idea on how customizations cost points, and how many you can use, and yes, the free *brawn* found on the astral juggernaut suit is always going to be there—**the free customizations are always found on those suits, you don’t need to choose them or pay for them, and you *can’t* reconfigure them.** They’re just always going to be there.